# Stability of dynamical system with purely imaginary eigenvalues

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I have a 4 dimensional dynamical system and I want to know the stability of one of its fixed points, the problem is that all the eigenvalues of the Jacobian there are purely imaginary:
$$
0 - 5.64799 i, 0 + 5.64799 i, 0 - 5.71808 i, 0 + 5.71808 i
$$

The eigenvectors of the Jacobian at the fix point are linearly independent and are the following:

$$
\left(-5 \sqrt{\frac{5}{192 \sqrt{5}-125}},1,0,0\right) \\
\left(5 \sqrt{\frac{5}{192 \sqrt{5}-125}},1,0,0\right) \\
\left(0,0,-5 i \sqrt{\frac{5}{125+64 \sqrt{5}}},1\right) \\
\left(0,0,5 i \sqrt{\frac{5}{125+64 \sqrt{5}}},1\right)
$$

What is the stability of this fix point and how can one figure it out?

Extra info:
My system is a continuous system of ODEs describing a physical system.

(I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238345/stability-of-dynamical-system-with-imaginary-eigenvalues) but I did not fully understand how it would apply to my case since he is talking about an eigenvalue with multiplicity 2.)

Comment: You can't determine stability from the eigenvalues alone if they lie on the imaginary axis, so there is no way to answer this question without knowing what the system is.

Comment: @HansLundmark Okay, is there any general procedure one can follow? could you send me in the right direction?

Comment: No, that was my point. You need to figure something out, depending on what the system actually looks like, so it will be different from case to case (and can in general be very difficult). Higher-order terms in the Taylor expansion may affect the phase portrait when the equilibrium is non-hyperbolic.